# Personagem do Nightmares não se move

Tags: unity3d

Estou com um problema no jogo Nightmares. Meu personagem não se move apenas faz a animação de Idle.

O *script* ta ai e parece não ter nenhum erro.

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 6f;

    Vector3 movement;
    Animator anim;
    Rigidbody playerRigidbody;
    int floorMask;
    float camRayLenght = 100f;

    void Awake ()
    {
        floorMask = LayerMask.GetMask ("Floor");
        anim = GetComponent <Animator> ();
        playerRigidbody = GetComponent <Rigidbody> ();

    }


    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        float h =Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float v =Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        Move (h,v);
        Turning ();
        Animating (h, v);

    }


    void Move (float h, float v)
    {

        movement.Set (h, 0f, v);

        movement = movement.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime ;

        playerRigidbody.MovePosition (transform.position + movement);

    }

    void Turning ()
    {

        Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);

        RaycastHit floorHit;

        if(Physics.Raycast (camRay, out floorHit, camRayLenght, floorMask))
        {

            Vector3 playerToMouse = floorHit.point - transform.position;

            playerToMouse.y = 0f;

            Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (playerToMouse);

            playerRigidbody.MoveRotation (newRotation);
        }




    }


    void Animating (float h,float v)
    {

        bool walking = h != 0f || v !=0f;

        anim.SetBool ("IsWalking", walking);
    }


}
```

Comment: Não sei se o problema é exatamente esse, mas se você tá usando `FixedUpdate` você *não precisa* ponderar a movimentação pelo `Time.deltaTime`. Talvez isso esteja diminuindo muitíssimo a velocidade de movimentação do personagem e assim o efeito é como se ele não se movesse. Tente trocar o nome do método para só `Update` **ou** retirar a multiplicação do valor de `Time.deltaTime` e veja se alguma dessas opções funciona.

Comment: O `FixedUpdate` atualiza a cada 0.02 segundos, o `deltaTime` não deveria afetar o movimento. Imagino que sejam algumas coisas, o script pode não estar no player por exemplo. @pedrofarah, poderia, por favor, adicionar um printscreen do Inspector do player. O player não move, ou também não gira em direção do mouse?

Comment: Tb nao gira em direçao ao mouse cara

Comment: valeu pela dica ai Luiz mas nao deu :(

Comment: @Nils Pode não ser esse o problema, mas o `deltaTime` certamente afeta o movimento *planejado*, não? Por exemplo, no código dele a "velocidade" definida é `6f`, e como ele multiplica pelo `deltaTime` (que, como você mesmo diz, é fixo em `0.02` nas chamadas de `FixedUpdate`) o valor *efetivo* da velocidade vai ser `0.02 * 6 = 0.12`. Assim, a cada quadro, o personagem vai ser mover apenas 0.12 do vetor unitário da Unity.

Comment: Pedro, outra coisa que eu só notei agora é que você está fazendo o movimento *apenas* com base nos eixos (de teclado/joystick), que conforme vc observa [na documentação](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxisRaw.html) devolvem valores no intervalo [-1, 1] (e no caso de teclado, apenas com os valores -1, 0 ou 1). Não faltou você usar ai também o [`transform.forward`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html) (pra mover o personagem na direção que ele está apontando/olhando)?

Comment: Tente assim: `playerRigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.forward * speed);`. Procure também colocar algumas mensagens de depuração (com [`Debug.Log`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html)) pra ver quais valores estão sendo calculados/utilizados no método `Move`.

Comment: Ainda naão deu luiz...o estranho é que fiz do jeitinho do video do nils...agr apareceu um problema no console..vou coloca-lo pra vcs verem

Comment: Ah. Tá explicado então (e o @Nils tinha razão). Você não adicionou um *rigid body* ao objeto do jogador, e assim quando faz `playerRigidbody.MovePosition (transform.position + movement);` nada acontece. Não sei como está o video do Nils, mas volte lá e preste atenção na parte em que ele adiciona esse componente ao objeto do jogador (via o botão *add component*). Faça isso e deve funcionar.

Comment: Finalmente deu certo cara...simples falta de atençao minha ...muito obrigado!!

Comment: Tem só mais um probleminha...quando ele anda, ele  não faz a animaçao "move" o tempo todo..faz uma vez e dps simplesmente se "arrasta"..é normal?

Comment: Não é normal, se o que você queria era a animação executando enquanto ele se move. Mas ai o problema é no seu grafo de animação, então volte no vídeo do Nils e olhe novamente se você não faltou com a atenção em alguma outra coisa relacionada. Se a dúvida permanecer, abra outra pergunta.

Comment: Valeu brother...o primeiro problema ja esta resolvido. Qto ao segundo,vou abrir uma nova pergunta

Comment: Essa pergunta [está sendo discutida no meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4186/pergunta-erroneamente-marcada-como-duplicada). Principalmente quem votou para fechar como duplicada, está convidado a participar da discussão. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Só pra pergunta ter uma resposta (e talvez ajudar outras pessoas no
>   futuro), vou postar aqui a conclusão dos comentários. Vale notar que o mérito da "solução" do problema do AP também é do @Nils. :)

Na inicialização do jogo, isto é, na chamada do método `Awake`, o seu código faz o seguinte:

```
playerRigidbody = GetComponent <Rigidbody> ();
```

Esse trecho do código obtém o componente `Rigidbody` anexado ao objeto atual (do jogador) e armazena na variável `playerRigidbody`.

Então, durante a movimentação, o seu código faz o seguinte:

```
playerRigidbody.MovePosition (transform.position + movement);
```

Essa chamada, do método `MovePosition` da classe `Rigidbody` somente vai funcionar se essa variável não estiver nula.

Como o próprio erro já indica (em inglês), não há um "corpo rígido" (do inglês, *rigid body*) anexado no objeto do jogador (no seu exemplo, o objeto `Player`):

> "*There is no 'Rigidbody' attached to the "Player" game object, but a
>   script is trying to access it.*"
>
> Em tradução livre:
>
> "Não há um componente 'Rigidbody' anexado ao objeto de jogo "Player",
>   mas um script está tentando acessá-lo."

Justamente, porque na sua chamada de `MovePosition` a variável `playerRigidbody` está nula, já que você esqueceu de anexar o componente 'Rigidbody' ao objeto do jogador.

Comment: @Luis Vieira, obrigado pela menção, mas você quem matou a charada, eu nem havia pensado nisso (eu achava que ele esqueceu de salvar o script ou pendurar ele no player). E bela explicação que você deu aqui na resposta, vou tentar aprender esta tua didática é bem clara, rápida e explicativa(modo bonito de dizer que vou plagiar na cara larga tua forma de explicar).

Comment: @Nils Se vc não tivesse pedido um printscreen do Inspector não daria pra ter certeza do problema. :) Pode "plagiar" sem medo! hehe Eu realmente acho que a melhor forma de ensinar as pessoas a serem auto-suficientes é mostrando que as mensagens de erro estão lá pra ajudar e não pra assustar.

Comment: @Nils Você que manja mais do assunto, poderia por favor fornecer uma resposta [nesta outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76604/73) do mesmo AP a respeito do porquê de ocorrer o erro quando o "Has Exit Time" influenciou? Pensei em pedir ao próprio AP pra fazer isso, mas acho que você tem mais chances de produzir uma resposta que seja útil pra outras pessoas no futuro (principalmente consumidores do seus vídeos). Eu também não entendo todas as nuances dessa configuração... :)