# Animaçao nao carrega -Nightmares

Tags: unity3d

No jogo Nightmares meu personagem, apesar de girar em torno do mouse, e se locomover, não realiza a Animação `Move` que era pra ser feita enquanto eles estivesse andando. Segue ai um *print* dos parâmetros e das animações inserir a descrição da imagem aqui.

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>


<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: Pedro, não leve a mal o comentário (só estou tentando te ajudar). A sua pergunta está bem mal feita. Você descreve um problema genérico que torna difícil às pessoas entendenrem (tanto que estão pensando que a pergunta é duplicata). Você poderia aprender com os erros da sua pergunta anterior e já fornecer nesta mais informações.

Comment: Pra começar, o que é "um jeito bugado"? Descreva de uma forma mais correta e *ilustre* com alguma imagem do jogo. Coloque na pergunta também mais informações sobre o seu grafo de animação (um screenshot dele com as regras de transição) e a parte do código onde você atualiza as variáveis utilizadas nas regras de transição da animação.

Comment: @mgibsonbr A pergunta dele não é realmente duplicada, é uma nova pergunta (dá uma olhada [nesses últimos comentários](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76319/personagem-do-nightmares-n%c3%a3o-se-move#comment156356_76319), pra entender). Ele é que não soube fornecer detalhes para deixá-la suficientemente clara. Mas a sua sugestão pra que ele a edite é válida (ou seja, pode manter o voto de fechar, se quiser, até ele seguir a sugestão).

Comment: Argh, quando a pergunta foi fechada meu comentário foi removido automaticamente... Nem lembro mais o que escrevi. Não sabia que o sistema fazia isso, das próximas vezes vou criar um comentário separado em vez de editar o comentário de pergunta duplicada.

Comment: Peço a compreensao de vcs caras pois sou novo no site..tentei explicar da melhor maneira possivel agora e mandei um print

Comment: Pedro, melhorou um bocado, mas ainda faltam informações na sua pergunta. Primeiro: a animação `Move` é iniciada alguma vez? Por exemplo, ela se inicia uma única vez assim que você inicia o movimento do personagem, e depois volta para `Idle`? Também faltam informações a respeito de quais são as condições de ativação das transições (as setinhas indo de `Idle` pra `Move` e vice-versa). Coloque também os prints dessas condições, e o trecho do código onde você faz o movimento, pois sem isso não dá pra saber onde está o seu erro.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Eu notei que havia sido removido, mas achei que foi você. Você só havia comentado que a pergunta parecia duplicada, e que se não fosse o AP deveria editá-la para melhorar seu conteúdo. Aliás, ela foi fechada logo depois que eu também votei (só que eu votei como não clara).

Comment: Luiz é o seguinte: apesar de se locomover o personagem nao faz a animaçao de "mexer as pernas" q deveria ser feita entende?

Comment: Ok. Bom, olhando as condições de ativação, eles estão amarradas a uma variável chamada `isWalking`. Se ela for `true`, ele vai do estado `Idle` para o estado `Move` e se for `false` vai do `Move` para o `Idle`. Pergunta 1: esta variável está sendo atualizada via código, com uma chamada do tipo: `animator.SetBool("isWalking", true);`? (aliás, porque vc **ainda** não postou o código?). Além disso, o "Has Exit Time" tá marcado nas duas transições. Pergunta 2: Isso tá certo? Tá igualzinho ao que o @Nils fez no vídeo dele? Não tá rolando uma falta de atenção em alguma coisa desse tipo?

Comment: Mais um vacilo meu..o erro estava no "Has exit Time"...valeu pela atençao e pela paciencia ai Luiz kkkk..valeu!!

Comment: Marcar o `has exit time` significa que a animação não pode mudar a qualquer momento. Geralmente você teria que encerrar o tempo do `Idle` para começar a do `Move`. Mas pelo menos o autor da pergunta veria ele caminhar após alguns segundos. Se expandir o `Settings` você pode determinar alguns parâmetros, como o tempo em que é permitido trocar animação, quando pode ser interrompida, duração da transição. Por exemplo, precisa executar pelo menos metade do tempo do `Idle` antes dele trocar, talvez estes valores estivessem muito grandes.

Comment: Geralmente `has exit time` é usado quando quer uma animação de ataque, ou de apanhar. Que executa uma vez e já volta para o estado anterior. Exemplo: O personagem está em movimento, e sofre um ataque. Cumprindo as condições do ataque acontece uma transição para a animação de `apanhar`, apanhar terá `has exit time` e assim que encerrar ela, volta para o move.

Comment: @Nils, por que você não cria uma resposta com esse conteúdo (dos comentários)? Essa resposta ia sim ser muito útil para futuros usuários. :)

Comment: Devido a similaridades nesta e outras questões, essa pergunta [*também* está sendo discutida no meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4186/pergunta-erroneamente-marcada-como-duplicada). Quem for votar pra fechar, por favor, acesse e participe da discussão antes de fazê-lo.

Comment: @Luiz Vieira, eu acho injusto, você acertou a resposta na mosca, só vim aqui dar pitacos. Nunca havia entrado no meta, acho que passei mais tempo vendo as perguntas de lá do que daqui. Tem muita coisa interessante acontecendo, acho que dei mais votos lá também.

Comment: @Nils Não se preocupe. Sério mesmo. O mais importante, na minha opinião, é o conteúdo ser suficientemente bom pra melhorar a qualidade do material de Unity por aqui. Por isso sugeri que você desse a resposta, já que você conhece mais do assunto. :)